# PhoneGap API return Timestamp format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In `phoneGap` there are two `APIs` one is `Geo-location` and other is `Accelerometer` both return `time-stamp` in `onSuccess` method in `Accelerometer` the `time-stamp` is looks like this `1386115200` but in `Geo-location` it gives like `Wed Dec 04 2013 01:41:03 ..`

I am using the `geolocation` `api` and when user start tracking then until user stops every 30 second i get `geolocation` `api` and push into `object` and after stop tracking i put that object in this `JSON.stringify` function so the `timestamp` become like this `2013-12-04T19:32:43.895Z` so how to i convert back this format like this `1386115200` because i need this format for my further processing steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a new `Date` object with the time string that you have then divide the `.getTime()` by 1000.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9gUq/1/)

```
function convertTimestamp(sTime) {
    return Math.round(new Date(sTime).getTime()/1000);
}
```